# Http post request to Google Script resulting in 411 error length required

Tags: http, google-apps-script, at-command

I am using AT Command (similar to C or C++) to send a post request to Google Script where it saves the data. I get the error saying 411 error.

This is the code sent:

```
AT+CHTTPACT="script.google.com",80

//Wait for the +CHTTPACT: REQUEST from the module
WAIT=1

POST script.google.com HTTP/1.1<cr><lf>
Host: script.google.com/macros/s/AKfycbwALy3GCY_r5fNOzxzut_RnbDR01Caq83MmsLPRuxoE5EQ7mUE/exec\r\nContent-Length: 0\r\nContent-Type: json/application<cr><lf>

<cr><lf>^z<cr><lf>
```

and this is the error:

```
+CHTTPACT: DATA,1408
http/1.0 411 length required
content-type: text/html; charset=utf-8
referrer-policy: no-referrer
content-length: 1564
date: wed, 06 mar 2019 12:36:35 gmt

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang=en>
  <meta charset=utf-8>
  <meta name=viewport content="initial-scale=1, minimum-scale=1, width=device-width">
  <title>Error 411 (Length Required)!!1</title>
  <style>
_150x54dp.png) no-repeat
+CHTTPACT: DATA,317
;-webkit-background-size:100% 100%}}#logo{display:inline-block;height:54px;width:150px}
  </style>
  <a href=//www.google.com/><span id=logo aria-label=Google></span></a>
  <p><b>411.</b> <ins>Thatâ€™s an error.</ins>
  <p>POST requests require a <code>Content-length</code> header.  <ins>Thatâ€™s all we know.</ins>

+CHTTPACT: 0
```

I got it working with my own Node JS server but I need it to work with json body so it works with Google and other cloud servers:

```
AT+CHTTPACT="59.102.xx.xxx",3000

//Wait for the +CHTTPACT: REQUEST from the module
WAIT=1


POST http://59.102.xx.xxx HTTP/1.1<cr><lf>
Host: http://59.102.xx.xxx:3000<cr><lf>
Content-Type: text/html<cr><lf>
<cr><lf>^z<cr><lf>
```

Comment: Well, did you set a valid content length header? The error states you did not.

Comment: I would if I new how to do this. I have added the code that works with my own node js server.

Comment: @Amir I think that if you are actually using the AT command, the value of ``Content-Type`` is wrong. Can you modify from ``json/application`` to ``application/json`` and try it again? If the error still occurs, as a test run, how about removing ``Content-Length`` and/or `Content-Type``? If these didn't resolve your issue, I apologize.

Comment: @Tanaike I did both and didnt work. The reason I added them was because google server would send that message in my post saying content length is required.

Comment: @Amir I apologize for the inconvenience. For example, as a test, when you access to the Web Apps using curl or others, what response will you get?

Comment: as I said above, I can get this working with my node server at home. So there has to be something about formatting my request. Did you have a json request in AT Command.